# rule length equal to length of item text paragraph

Tags: enumitem, lengths

How can I get  the width of the  rule equal to the text  for each  item paragraph ? Any advice ?

```
\documentclass[french,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%-----------------------------------------------------
%macro puce
%-----------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\mapuce}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base),overlay]
\node[rectangle,inner sep=5pt,text centered,text=white,fill=#1,font=\bfseries](a){#2};
\draw[#1,line width=1pt](a.north west)--(a.north east)--++(4em,0em);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\setenumerate[1]{label=\protect\mapuce{red}{\arabic*},labelsep=1em,itemsep=1.1\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\mapuce{cyan}{\arabic*}]
\item  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\item Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. 
\item  eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
\end{enumerate}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the rule go to the right margin, or to the end of the item text?

Comment: @Bernard to the right margin for each item text.

Comment: Replace this line in your code:`\draw[#1,line width=1pt](a.north west)--(a.north east)--++(\linewidth+3.5pt,0em);` Note that `\linewidth` calculates the current width of the line and `3.5pt` is necessary to compensate the width of the rectangle and the line thickness that you defined.

Comment: By the way you had a mistake in your line of code at `\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\mapuce{cyan}{\arabic*}]` Make sure you make the correction.

Comment: @azetina, I want that the length of rule change as  the length of text changed for the first line of item. Is it clear ?

Comment: It will change try it.

Comment: I will do thanks

Comment: If I have this phrase in first item **somme words** I'd like that the length of rule to be  equal to the length of **somme words**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a MWE example looking at the changes that you recommend. I have also added a few changes regarding the entire width of the text and current text.

```
\documentclass[french,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%-----------------------------------------------------
%macro puce
%-----------------------------------------------------
\newlength\mapucetextwidth %defines length of the current line

\newcommand{\mapuceitem}[1]{%
\setlength{\mapucetextwidth}{\widthof{#1}}% Saves the current line width
\item {#1}%
}
\newcommand{\mapuce}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base),overlay]
\node[rectangle,inner sep=5pt,text centered,text=white,fill=#1,font=\bfseries](a){#2};
\draw[#1,line width=1pt](a.north west)--(a.north east)--++(\mapucetextwidth+3.5pt,0em); % implements the current line width
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\setenumerate[1]{label=\protect\mapuce{red}{\arabic*},labelsep=1em,itemsep=1.1\baselineskip}



\begin{document}

\section{}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\mapuce{cyan}{\arabic*}]
\mapuceitem{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\mapuceitem{Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}
\mapuceitem{eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean}
\end{enumerate}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that if you want all the `textwidth` to be considered you can simply replace the following line in your code.

```
\draw[#1,line width=1pt](a.north west)--(a.north east)--++(\linewidth+3.5pt,0em);
```

Note that `\linewidth` calculates the current width of the line and `3.5pt` is necessary to compensate the width of the rectangle and the line thickness that you defined.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want: in the `\draw` command, at the end of the tikzpicture, I replaced `4em` with `\linewidth` (which is, a this place, the text width in the list).

```
 \documentclass[french,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%-----------------------------------------------------
%macro puce
%-----------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\Mapuce}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base),overlay]
\node[rectangle,inner sep=5pt,text centered,text=white,fill=#1,font=\bfseries](a){#2};
\draw[#1,line width=1pt](a.north west)--(a.north east)--++(\linewidth,0em);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\protect\Mapuce{red}{\arabic*}, labelsep=1em, itemsep=1.1\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\Mapuce{cyan}{\arabic*}]%
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\item Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\item eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]